# DAO pattern - where should I put static variables?

Tags: java, design-patterns, dao

I've a web app that use a JSP Model 2 architecture.

I use a DAO pattern too; in particular, different methods need values like `productID` that I want to be unique.

```
/**
 * Updates the productID that is unique per JVM run.
 * @return the updated value of <i>productID</i>
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException if an error occurs with the connection to the database
 */
public static synchronized int createProductID() throws ClassNotFoundException{
    int maxID = QueriesDAO.maxIDInDatabase("product");
    while(productID <= maxID) {
        productID++;
    }
    return productID++;
}
```

That method queries the database and gives back a new ID, that is stored in `private static int productID = 0;` (0 is the first value assigned).

What I want to ask is: where should I put that query and that variable?

For now, I have a package named `DAO` where I have all the queries, like queries for the users on `UserDAO.java`, or for the products on `ProductDAO.java` and so on. The `createProductID()` method and the variable linked are stored in the Main class, but that doesn't seems to me the right place. How can I change my pattern?

Using an interface can be a solution? But with the interface, I can't have private fields that can host the `productID` variables..

Comment: The answer is "don't do that". For example, what if you have copies running on multiple servers? Instead, use a database sequence or let your persistence provider do that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why do you need to query the maximum id?**

You're database or persistence provider should be able to provide an auto-incrementing sequential value that will be automatically assigned to your products upon inserting them into the database meaning you never need to know what the id is before you insert.

See [MySQL auto increment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)

**If there is a good reason that you need the id before insert:**

Consider using GUID. These are not sequentially generated IDs (in most cases) and so there is no need to worry about querying your maximum ID from the database first.

With regards to where you should store this - you don't need to. Java's `UUID` class is part of the `util` package and can be called statically anywhere and is thread safe.

Check out the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) [JavaDoc]

Also a good article on using UUID can be found [here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids/) [Coding Horrors]